# Saving HTML Table Object(s)

Tags: html, node-red

[image: Table View]

Blocked out the data for personal reasons.
Essentially I am passing images from a MongoDB to NodeRed and parsing the actual image file back to base64 to create a set of up to 100 images (records) and the "alarm" description. The table is done in HTML template with input coming from Mongo Query.

With 3 pieces of information that is "linked" together (Time, Alarm, Image) the information separately does no good.

What I'm trying to determine if there is a good way to download the full table (images included) in a logical way.

Methods tried:
Excel download - Formatted properly, rows/columns exist but images are not saved properly because they technically aren't being stored in the table, just referencing from the MongoDB Query.

[image: Excel Cell where image is saved]

Canvas->Table inside Canvas: this one has yielded little success. Idea: Make a canvas and have the table inside (yielding an image that could be saved, removing search-ability but easy to view). Either I don't fully understand how HTML canvas drawing works or Node-Red handles some things differently. I got a blank canvas when linking table to canvas by object ID of table.

SelectAll/Copy/Paste: This one works, pasting into a doc has everything formatted in table, but not automated/scripted.

Looking for a way to "triggered"/on button press to save the current table contents and save them. CtrlP/print to PDF and such work fine. Looking specifically to save the Table or an object similar in nature.

I cannot post/link the flow because of data/security reasons.

If there is a better option for managing data that needs to be in a format with 3 columns and 100 rows I am also open to changing the HTML. I am not an expect in best practices for frontend, this is only going to be used for creating a report.

Comment: What about saving the page with strg+s? That also saves the pictures.

Comment: I haven't had success using Ctrl+S to save the whole page if that's the suggestion. That was the first thing I tried and when trying to reopen the page it doesn't load properly. Not sure if a NodeRed issue or something else.

Comment: It really isn't clear what you are asking here. What is the end goal? You say "save" the table, but it sounds like you already have all the data in the database.